# Horizontal slide between two div

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I would like to create a slide beteween **two divs** when I **click on a link**.

I'm trying to do a slide like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/

But this is a disaster : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/SP5Rh/

```
$('.slide').click(function() {

    $('.green').animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('.red').css('left', '150%');
        $('.red').appendTo('#container');
    });

    $('.green').next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with using your first jsfiddle?

Comment: In fact I tried to do like the first jsfiddle but with two divs and with a click on a link not on the divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it, i've changed the numbers a bit, to fix it for your box size.

```
$('.slide').click(function() {

    $("#container div:first").animate({
        left: '-150%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $('#container div:first').next().animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 500);
});
```

EDIT: Why didn't yours work, compared to the working one? 
You were animating either `red` or `green` alone. Also, the other one has `next()` being used, but yours cannot have that because `next()` for your `Slide div` anchor is not what we want here.

Comment: @Xroad I'm sorry, I didn't get you. The jsfiddle looks fine, I don't see any overlaps.

Comment: @xFortyFourx Thank you for your help. Here is the real structure of my page : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/SP5Rh/4/
The other particularity is that the red div is by default at "left :150px" and the green div "top: -150px"

Comment: @Xroad you're again making the same mistake :). In your javascript, replace `.div-main` with `div`.

Comment: @xFortyFourx lol ouch. Ok I updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/SP5Rh/4/
The other particularity is that the red div is by default at "left :150px" and the green div "top: -150px"